# Make the whole notebook not editable

Tags: notebooks, options

How can I set all the cells in the notebook `not editable`?
I don't want that a user can change phrases and letters.

Comment: Lookup `Editable`, `Deployed` etc. Maybe even `CDFDeploy`.

Comment: @Kuba I tried this at the beninning of the notebook, SetOptions[NotebookObject[EvaluationNotebook[]], Deployed -> True] , but it didn't work.

Comment: Strip `NotebookObject` it is misused. `EvaluationNotebook[]` is enough.

Comment: @Kuba Like that works, but using that,  I can't see anyone of the outputs of my functions.

Comment: You mean you can't evaluate cells? Why didn't you start with `Editable` then?

Comment: Module[{},nb =EvaluationNotebook[];
           FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["SelectAll"]];
           SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], Deletable -> False,Editable -> False];];

I wrote this and seems working

Comment: @Ale1794 If you found a solution, you can post it as an answer, self-answering is encouraged here. :)